# How to copy daily posts from other website to you website

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to copy the daily posts from a wordpress site to my website automatically?

I need to copy the daily results that they are posting to my website.

Comment: Both Sites are yours ????

Comment: Sorry for the late response. No, the other website is not mine. But they are posting public information that I want to feed from my wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't providing enough information.

1. Wordpress.org or wordpress.com?
2. If your sites are on Wordpress.org, use these plugins on the wordpress site you want to show the posts:
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator/
   http://wordpress.org/plugins/rsskingpro/

But the output of those plugins aren't so great, so you will probably need to do some css styling and plugin customising.

If both sites aren't wordpress.org you can make a Jquery hack to get the posts from the wordpress site but this wont work if both sites are on different servers.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It's wordpress.com

I'm not sure if what is the platform of the website that I'm planning to feed data.